# Merge 2 query where an index is missing

Tags: php, mysql

I need to merge result of 2 query result where in the second query, an index is missing.

Example:

```
query 1: SELECT A.ID AS ID1, B.ID AS ID2 WHERE......

// var_dump();
$result_1 = array(
  0 => array(
       ID1 => 1,
       ID2 => 5
  ),
  1 => array(
       ID1 => 5,
       ID2 => 4
  ),
  2 => array(
       ID1 => 7,
       ID2 => 6
  ),
 3 => array(
       ID1 => 7,
       ID2 => 8
  )
);

query 2: SELECT A.ID AS ID1 WHERE......

// var_dump();
$result_2 = array(
  0 => array(
       ID1 => 5
  ),
  1 => array(
       ID1 => 9
  ),
  2 => array(
       ID1 => 10
  )
);
```

I'd like to automatically insert a NULL value in the query 2 for each index: ID2 => NULL so i can merge:

```
$result_3 = array_merge($result_1, $result_2);
```

Can I do with query or must I've to iterate $result_2 after query2 is executed?

Like:

```
foreach ( $result_2 as $i => $v ) {
   $result_2[$i]["ID2"] = NULL;
}

$result_3 = array_merge($result_1, $result_2);
```

My goal, btw, is to have this result:

```
$result_3 = array(
      0 => array(
           ID1 => 1,
           ID2 => 5
      ),
      1 => array(
           ID1 => 5,
           ID2 => 4
      ),
      2 => array(
           ID1 => 7,
           ID2 => 6
      ),
      3 => array(
           ID1 => 7,
           ID2 => 8
      ),
      4 => array(
           ID1 => 9,
           ID2 => NULL
      ),
      5 => array(
           ID1 => 10,
           ID2 => NULL
      )
    );
```

You can see that i've not inserted index 0 from $result_2 cause ID1 is already inserted and ID2 is NULL.

EDIT: I've write this solution. It works but i'd like to know if there is a good solution in term of performance:

```
$result_2 = //resultset of SELECT A.ID AS ID1, NULL AS ID2 ....

$result_3 = $result_1;

    foreach ( $result_2 as $i => $v ) {

        if ( !in_array($v['ID1'],array_column($result_1, "ID1")) ) {

            $result_3[] = $result_2[$i];
        }

    }
```

Comment: If NULL is needed you have to iterate else you should have a look on array_merge_recursive

Comment: Would there be only `ID1` and `ID2` always?

Comment: @Akshay yes. And $result_1 is always returned. $result_2 is filtered: if ID1 from $result_2 is already present in $result_1, no operation needed. If ID1 from $result_2 is not present yet inside $result_1, then I add it to $result_3. Example of my code added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alter your select so that you select NULL as a second value...

```
SELECT A.ID AS ID1, null as ID2 WHERE
```

Comment: Not sure how your doing your query, but you may be able to do them both in 1 statement.  If the join to table B is done by a join - look into left join, this will mean if the record in table B isn't found, the values will be null.

Comment: My true queries are more complex than this example. So i need to execute 2 different queries.